# HIGHCHARTS - Given a series with UNIX stamps and values pairs for the data, how do I show only the date for the first and last point on xAxis?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Given the following data:

```
  series = [{
    data: [
      [1564686000000, 1500],
      [1562007600000, 2000],
      [1559415600000, 10],
      [1556737200000, 10],
      [1554145200000, 1000],
      [1551470400000, 435],
      [1549051200000, 500],
      [1546372800000, 10],
      [1543694400000, 130],
      [1541098800000, 120],
      [1538420400000, 1000],
      [1535828400000, 50],
      [1533150000000, 2000],
    ]
```

How can I configure HighCharts (line-chart) to only show the date for the first and last point dates within xAixs with the format `%b %Y`?

I am currently achieving this by getting the first and last elements from the series data string and passing to xAxis.tickPositions. I wonder if there's another way that doesn't require accessing the series data string.

I also would like to align left the first xAxis label with its ticker and align right the last xAxis label with its ticker. (see image below for better understanding). I can achieve this with CSS, but I wonder if I can set that anyhow using HighCharts API interface.

Here is an image of what I'm looking to achieve:

[image: example]

Comment: Could you prepare an online demo of what you already have?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to achieve what I was asking on this question.

For the yAxis I'm using `yAxis.tickPositioner` and for the xAxis I'm using `xAxis.tickPositions`

Here is a working example:

https://jsfiddle.net/vinicius5581/6kpxbyr3/68/